# Parser for Column with Date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, parsing

How can I parser all the sales and date column in the dataframe below

```
import pandas as pd 

data = [['30-06-2021', 43578, '31-01-2022', 5000, '28-02-2022', 78564, '31-03-2022', 52353, '30-04-2022'], 
        ['14-06-2021', 4475, '14-01-2022', 2546, '05-02-2022', 5757, '28-03-2022', 2352, '01-04-2022']]
ds = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Start', 'Sales_Jan-22', 'Jan-22', 'Sales_Feb-22', 'Feb-22', 'Sales_Mar-22', 'Mar-22',
                                   'Sales_Apr-22', 'Apr-22'])

    Start    Sales_Jan-22 Jan-22  Sales_Feb-22 Feb-22 Sales_Mar-22 Mar-22 Sales_Apr-22 Apr-22
0   30-06-2021  43578   31-01-2022  5000    28-02-2022  78564   31-03-2022  52353   30-04-2022
1   14-06-2021  4475    14-01-2022  2546    05-02-2022  5757    28-03-2022  2352    01-04-2022
```

So far, this is what I have done. However I received an error for the `Sales_%b-%y` and `%b-%y`

```
from dateutil import parser

gross_date = parser.parse(ds['Start'][0])
sales_col = parser.parse(ds['Sales_%b-%y'][0])
monthly_date = parser.parse(ds['%b-%y'][0])
```

How should I do the parser for date format? My desired output should be like this

```
    Start     Sales_Jan-22 Jan-22 Sales_Feb-22 Feb-22 Sales_Mar-22 Mar-22 Sales_Apr-22  Apr-22 Total
0   30-06-2021  43578   31-01-2022  5000    28-02-2022  78564   31-03-2022  52353   30-04-2022  3525
1   14-06-2021  4475    14-01-2022  2546    05-02-2022  5757    28-03-2022  2352    01-04-2022  63747
```

Because later I'm going to use is create a formula to get the `Total` column as shown above.

Comment: You don't have a column called "Sales_%b-%y". What exactly are you trying to do? What is your expected output?

Comment: @not_speshal I do have the column but in monthly basis i.e. `Sales_Jan-22`, `Sales_Feb-22` and so on. And here. I'm trying to parsing all this monthly sales into one and since they have different monthly, so I code it as `Sales_%b-%y`. Because later I'm going to use all this 3 names i.e `gross_date`, `sales_col` and `monthly_date` to create a formula for calculation. However this code `Sales_%b-%y` turn out to be an error. My problem is how can I turn this date format before I can parser it?

Comment: Yes "Sales_Jan-22" is not the same as "'Sales_%b-%y'" when you don't specify what `%b` and `%y` are.  Please include your expected output (dataframe) in the question. There may be easier ways to get what you need.

Comment: @not_speshal okay done! I've edit by putting my desired output. Anyway the `Total` column is not the sum that could easily using pd.DataFrame.sum. It's more longer than that, where I need to get the duration in years first, then power-of multiply then total of all month.

Comment: What does the "Total" column show? The sum of sales in the rows is 179495 and 15130

Comment: @not_speshal Nope. It's just the dummy number for  the desired value in `Total` whereby the `Total` is actually taking long way to calculate it. And that's is the reason I'm using pyhton. I'm just putting any values to show my desired dataframe table. Anyway, the later coding the get the desired `Total`, I already know. I only have problem with this `Sales_%b-%y` error on how to declare it before using parsing.

Comment: You don't need that. If you just want the total sales, you can simply do: `ds["Total"] = ds.filter(like="Sales").sum(1)`. Is that what you need?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can use `pd.to_datetime` to force convert all the date values and leave the numbers unchanged:

```
ds = ds.apply(pd.to_datetime, errors="ignore", format="%d-%m-%Y")
```

To check the values have been converted:

```
>>> ds["Start"].iat[1]
Timestamp('2021-06-14 00:00:00')
>>> ds["Jan-22"].iat[0]
Timestamp('2022-01-31 00:00:00')
```